# Displaying a text data while hovering over the image [React Functional Component]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was trying to implement this functionality to display some text when we hover over an Image.

I am using functional Component for this.

so heres what i did until now but the

tag is appearing above the image itself , i wanted that to display when i hover over the image .

So far :

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState("nodisplay");

const HoverData = "Click or pinch to Zoom Image";

const onHover = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        setHover("displayed")
        console.log("hovered")
        
    }

    const onHoverOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setHover("nodisplay")
    }

<div className="flex_center py-5">

<p className={hover} 
 onMouseEnter={(e)=>onHover(e)}
 onMouseLeave={(e)=>onHoverOver(e)}>
{HoverData}
</p>
<Image
   alt=""
  src="Some Img Link"                                                                           
  className="img-responsive"
/>
</div>
```

so the display is something like this , when i hover on the image i can see in console that i did hover there.

[Image for current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSJAO.png)

Any help is appreciated!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to show text when you hover over `image` you should call mouse events on `img` tag as follows. Also change data type of `hover` state to `boolean`.

```js
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false); // initial false

  const HoverData = "Click or pinch to Zoom Image";

  const onHover = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHover(true); // turn true
    console.log("hovered");
  };

  const onHoverOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // turn false
    setHover(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="flex_center py-5">
      {/* if hover is true then only show the text */}
      {hover && <p className={hover}>{HoverData}</p>}
      <img
        onMouseEnter={(e) => onHover(e)}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => onHoverOver(e)}
        alt=""
        src="some image link"
        className="img-responsive"
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Refer the link for preview: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-hover-st3x3w?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use ANTD (ant design) component to reach your goal. Use tooltip component doc: https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#header

Comment: Thanks for the docs @K Y , i have look at it and trying to implement this now !

Answer (score 0):

you should put onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave on the "img" tag not on "p" tag